# Extending MatRowDef

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I want to display some custom component/html between two rows on click. I believe the quick and easy solution would be to use the event from the click handler and manipulate the DOM directly however I'd like to do it *the angular way* if possible.

For inspiration I first looked at [this article](https://medium.com/@jsayol/having-fun-with-angular-extending-ngfor-to-support-for-in-f30c724967ed) on extending structural directive. It was of limited use though since `*matRowDef` isn't supposed to be used on its own, but in conjunction with other elements as part of the material table. I then went to have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/table/row.ts#L39) directly and tried to mimic the way `MatRowDef` extended `CdkRowDef` and ended up with this:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[expandableRowDef]',
  providers: [
    {provide: MatRowDef, useExisting: ExpandableRowDirective},
    {provide: CdkRowDef, useExisting: ExpandableRowDirective}
  ],
  inputs: ['columns: expandableRowDefColumns', 'when: expandableRowDefWhen']
})
export class ExpandableRowDirective<T> extends MatRowDef<T> {
  constructor(template: TemplateRef<any>,
              viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
              _differs: IterableDiffers) {
                super(template, _differs);
              }
}
```

I then simply switched `*matRowDef="..."` with `*expandableRowDef="..."`, it compiles fine and doesn't fail at runtime.

Where should I take it from here to edit the DOM inside the created `mat-row` element?

Comment: Hi @Reno, you have the ElementRef injected in your directive, and it will be the same reference of element Ref as mat-row have. With ElementRef you can acces dom and edit it if you want.

Comment: where is your custom template to insert?

Answer (score 2):

I had a basic requirement for something similar a while ago, and managed to put something together based off the discussion and broken plunkr on [this thread](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5936#issuecomment-318513544).

It essentially works by creating a custom component using [**`ComponentFactory`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory) and then using [**`@ViewChildren`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) to get a list of the table rows, and on click of the selected table row inserts the custom component at the specified `index` passing in the row data using [**`@Input`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Input):

**Template:**

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let index = index" 
  (click)="insertComponent(index)"
  #tableRow  
  matRipple>
</mat-row>
```

**Component:**

```
export class TableBasicExample {

  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChildren('tableRow', { read: ViewContainerRef }) rowContainers;
  expandedRow: number;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  insertComponent(index: number) {
    if (this.expandedRow != null) {
      // clear old content
      this.rowContainers.toArray()[this.expandedRow].clear();
    }

    if (this.expandedRow === index) {
      this.expandedRow = null;
    } else {
      const container = this.rowContainers.toArray()[index];
      const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(InlineMessageComponent);
      const inlineComponent = container.createComponent(factory);

      inlineComponent.instance.user = this.dataSource.data[index].name;
      inlineComponent.instance.weight = this.dataSource.data[index].weight;
      this.expandedRow = index;
    }
  }
}
```

Custom component which gets inserted between the rows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inline-message',
  template: 'Name: {{ user }} | Progress {{ progress}}%',
  styles: [`...`]
})
export class InlineMessageComponent {
  @Input() user: string;
  @Input() weight: string;
}
```

I have created a basic working demo of this on StackBlitz [**here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxznk8). Since this functionality is not officially supported yet, doing it in this way may eventually break down the line, however the Angular Material team does have something similar [in the pipeline](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5917).